# Quill Editor: cannot paste any text, input loses focus

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, quill

I'm trying to paste any random text into the `quill@1.3.7` editor, but all of my paste events are pretty much ignored. In addition, the cursor disappears - ie, the `<div>` loses focus.

Do I have to do something to get basic/default clipboard paste to work?  According the docs, those should be turned on by default since they are required.

I have `debug` turned on, and this is what I see in Chrome.

[image]

Here is how I'm initializing the editor:

```html
<div ref="editorElement" class="ql-editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

```js
import Quill from 'quill';

@customElement('quill-editor')
export class QuillEditorComponent {

  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay })  value: string;
  editorElement: any;
  editor: Quill;

  attached() { 

    var toolbarOptions = [/* removed for brevity */];

    this.editor = new Quill(this.editorElement, {
    debug: true,
      modules: { 
        toolbar: toolbarOptions,
        clipboard: {
            matchVisual: false
        }
      },
      placeholder: 'I have something to say...',
      theme: 'snow'
    });

    this.editor.root.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Filed an issue, as this seems to be a Chrome related issue:
https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/3512